# Dynamically added bootstrap drop-downs not functioning

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

In my html page i need to do an ajax call and based on response i need to add multiple drop-downs. 
[image: ajax loaded bootstrap dropdowns]

But my drop-downs are not functioning.
Below is the ajax call success load code

```
success : function(json) {
             var json_obj = null,contenttb='';
             json_obj =$.parseJSON(json.datas);

            for (var i in json_obj)
            {                    
                 // start
                contenttb += '<tr><td class="dropdown user-menu">';
                contenttb += '<button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class=" icon-ellipsis-vertical"></i> Actions</button>';
                contenttb += '<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#lead_update" class="lead_update_data"  data-id="' + json_obj[i].id + '" data-first_name="' + json_obj[i].First_Name + '"  > Edit Lead</a></li>';

                contenttb += '<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#open_popup" class="open" data-lead_id="' + json_obj[i].id + '"  >Open</a></li>';
                contenttb += '<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#tasklist" class="tasklist"  data-id="' + json_obj[i].id + '">Tasks</a></li>';
                contenttb += '</ul></td></tr>';
                //end
            }
           $('#result2').html(contenttb);

}
```

content is loaded to "result2" div.

But when I click on action button on each row  dropdowns are not functioning.

i even tried to call

```
 $("button.dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
```

after loading the content. But No changes

Comment: can you try removing class `dropdown-toggle` from button and simply try `$("button.btn").dropdown();`.

Comment: @vijayP I tried but still no effect

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: @Prateek No errors